# AlmaLinux 8.5 yum update fails due to ImageMagic conflicts

Tags: linux, centos

At the time of **ImageMagic** installation, I used the following commands.

`dnf --enablerepo=powertools install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel`

Now I am going update my AlmaLinux 8.5 server using the command `yum update`. But I am getting the following error.

```
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/config-Q16/configure.xml from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/aai.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/aai.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/art.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/art.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/avs.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/avs.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/bgr.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/bgr.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/bmp.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/bmp.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/braille.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/braille.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/cals.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/cals.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/caption.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/caption.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/cin.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/cin.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/cip.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/cip.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/clip.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/clip.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/cmyk.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/cmyk.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/cut.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/cut.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/dcm.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/dcm.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/dds.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/dds.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/debug.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/debug.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/dib.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/dib.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/dng.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/dng.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/dot.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/dot.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/dpx.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/dpx.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/ept.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/ept.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/exr.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/exr.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/fax.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/fax.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/fits.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/fits.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/gif.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/gif.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/gradient.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/gradient.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/gray.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/gray.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/hald.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/hald.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/hdr.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/hdr.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/histogram.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/histogram.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/hrz.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/hrz.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/html.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/html.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/icon.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/icon.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/info.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/info.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/inline.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/inline.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/ipl.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/ipl.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/jbig.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/jbig.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/jnx.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/jnx.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/jp2.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/jp2.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/jpeg.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/jpeg.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/json.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/json.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/label.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/label.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mac.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mac.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/magick.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/magick.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/map.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/map.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mask.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mask.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mat.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mat.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/matte.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/matte.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/meta.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/meta.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/miff.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/miff.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mono.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mono.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mpc.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mpc.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mpr.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mpr.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/msl.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/msl.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mtv.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mtv.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mvg.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/mvg.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/null.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/null.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/otb.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/otb.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/palm.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/palm.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/pango.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/pango.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/pattern.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/pattern.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/pcd.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/pcd.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/pcl.la from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.9.12/modules-Q16/coders/pcl.so from install of ImageMagick-libs-0:6.9.12.48-2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick6-libs-1:6.9.12.44-1.el8.remi.x86_64
```

That's why my server update fails. Don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: --disablerepo=remi

Answer (score 0):

I disabled epel:

```
dnf config-manager --disable epel
```

After that I was able to install ImageMagick.

Comment: Can you explain why this would make a difference?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.